# Como posso fazer a selection desta DataTable?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Criei um datatable de colunas variáveis cuja coleção se dá a partir de uma lista de objetos com vários atributos diferentes. Detalhando, tenho uma classe AvaliaProjeto, que possui um atributo Projeto, um Criterio e uma Escala.

A quantidade de colunas se dá pelo número de critérios + 1 (para colocar o projeto), onde o header é o nome do critério e o valor é a sua escala (que é diferente para cada projeto). Contudo, como são de vários atributos diferentes, estou numa dúvida intensa sobre como posso selecionar esta linha para futuras alterações.

Seguem o POJO de AvaliaProjeto, o código da Table e o Código do ManagedBean que usa a Table.

DataTable

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" class="dataTable" value="#{topsisBean.nProjetos}" rows="10" paginator="true" 
        paginatorPosition="bottom" emptyMessage="Nenhuma avaliação de projeto cadastrada" binding="#{topsisBean.dataTable}"
        selection="?????" selectionMode="single">
        <p:columns value="#{topsisBean.columns}" var="c" headerText="#{c.header}">
            <h:outputText value="#{c.property}" />
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
```

POJO

```
package br.com.somore.model.pojo.topsis;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import br.com.somore.control.SampleEntity;

@Entity
@Table(name="avaliaprojeto", schema="somore")
public class AvaliaProjeto implements Serializable, SampleEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idAvaliaProjeto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idProjeto")
    private Projeto projeto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idCriterio")
    private Criterio criterio;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idEscala")
    private Escala escala;

    double valorCriterio;

    //Gets Sets e Construtor
}
```

ManagedBean

```
package br.com.somore.control.beans;

//imports

@ManagedBean(name="topsisBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TopsisBean implements Serializable {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //DataTable
    DataTable dataTable;
    int nProjetos = 0;


    static public class ColumnModel implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String header;
        private String property;

        public ColumnModel(String header, String property) {
            this.header = header;
            this.property = property;
        }

        public String getHeader() {
            return header;
        }

        public String getProperty() {
            return property;
        }
    }

    private int countCriterios() {
        int i = 0;
        Projeto p = avaliaProjetos.get(0).getProjeto();

        for(AvaliaProjeto ap : avaliaProjetos) {
            if(ap.getProjeto().equals(p))
                i++;
        }

        return i;
    }

    private void organizarColumns() {   
        List<AvaliaProjeto> aux = (avaliaProjetos = avaliaProjetoDAO.listar()); 
        int count = countCriterios();
        columns = new ArrayList<>();

        projetos = new ArrayList<>();

        for(AvaliaProjeto ap : aux) {
            //Se não há nenhum projeto, adiciona-se um projeto
            if(projetos.isEmpty()) {
                projetos.add(ap.getProjeto());
                nProjetos++;
            }

            //Se o projeto não está contido, adiciona-se um novo projeto
            if( ! projetos.contains(ap.getProjeto())) {
                projetos.add(ap.getProjeto());
                nProjetos++;
            }
        }

        for(Projeto p : projetos) {
            columns.add(new ColumnModel(
                "Projeto",
                p.getNomeProjeto()
            ));
        }

        //A partir da lista auxiliar de avaliações de projeto, busca-se o critério e escala desejados
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            columns.add(new ColumnModel(
                    aux.get(i).getCriterio().getNomeCriterio(),
                    verificarTipoCriterio(aux.get(i))
            ));
        }
    }

    private String verificarTipoCriterio(AvaliaProjeto ap) {
        if(ap.getValorCriterio() != 0)
            return String.valueOf(ap.getValorCriterio());
        else
            return ap.getEscala().getImpactoEscala();
    }
}
```

Foto

[image: DataTable de Avaliação de Projetos]

O ideal seria se houvesse a possibilidade de pegar toda linha do dataTable. Tentei fazer um binding da Table. Mas não vi como posso pegar a linha selecionada por lá :(.

Comment: Se precisarem de mais alguma coisa, só pedir que edito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dataTable` possui atributos justamente pra essa situação que são o `selection="#{topsisBean.projetoSelecionado}"` e `rowSelectListener="#{topsisBean.onRowSelect}"`

E no seu ManagedBean

```
private Projeto projetoSelecionado; // + get /set

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
    // Para recuperar o Projeto no click basta fazer isso
    // ((Projeto) event.getObject());  

    // sua ação futura
}
```

Mais atributos e outras exemplos só dar uma olhada [aqui](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf).

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Maicon.